# Do deployment on Cloud Run using gcloud uses resources and cost money?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I deployed two APIs to Google Cloud RUN. I used Dockerfiles to build the images directly on the Cloud Infrastructure. It took me quite a lot of tries to deploy the APIs. After the deployment I barely used them. I used this two commands to build and deploy the images

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/${SAMPLE}

gcloud beta run deploy ${SAMPLE} \
  --set-env-vars GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT} \
  --image gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/${SAMPLE} --timeout=30m  --cpu 4 --memory 4Gi --concurrency 1 --execution-environment gen2
```

What did this command exactly do? The image is built on my computer and then uploaded to the google cloud infrastructure? I am asking this questing because I was surprised that I in the billing I have to pay 24€. Is that the deployment cost? Or because of the few times I used the APIs? Any idea?

[image]

Comment: `gcloud builds sumbit` will not build the image on your local machine. it sends the files to a GCS bucket and uses Cloud Build to build the image then push it to GCR. so you will be charged for Cloud Build, Cloud Storage, and GCR services! and since you deployed the image to Cloud Run, you will be paying for Cloud Run as well!
review the pricing docs of each service to understand more or use the pricing calculator.

Comment: As you can see you used 275€ worth of cloud run resources, that is very, very, very far away from "barely used them". Either you are often spinning up machines by calling your cloud run instances or someone else is. I assume you ran out of free credits with that €236.90 promotion, so anything more will be billed to you.

Comment: If the deployment is considered as cloud run resources then that could make sense, but still very expensive.

Comment: It seems more of a billing issue. For faster resolution you may raise a billing issue [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing)

Comment: It's also possible that your API was being invoked by a 3rd party since you didn't deploy it with ```--no-allow-unauthenticated``` flag. Not using the flag means your API is open to anyone who has the URL and there are bots out there that just brute force url generation and visit them. Using the flag means your API can only be invoked using generated tokens or a service account which means random people can't invoke it

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the command, it looks like your cloud run instance has the following settings.

```
--cpu 4 --memory 4Gi --concurrency 1
```

These settings mean that each CR Container will have 4Gi of memory, 4 CPUs, and will spin up 1 container per request. Because the concurrency is set to 1, each container spin up will also have a "cold-start" cost to it.

Just from eye-balling these settings, if you have alot of request going to this cloud run service, I wouldn't be surprised that it has costed this much, if not more.

Here is the GCP pricing calculator. Input the data needed and see how much you could save by lowering resources on the service.

https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=